# To com dúvida meta charset utf8 ou http-equiv

Tags: css, html5

Agente to na dúvida qual meta tag e mais correto ser usado ou se e certo usar as duas. Meta charset utf8 ou meta http-aqui = content- linguagem contanto = pt-br.
Me ajudem por favor

Comment: as duas marcações tem funções semanticas distintas. qual sua dúvida?

Answer (score -1):

`<meta charset="utf-8">` diz respeito a encodificação dos caracteres para o navegador, por exemplo, alguns navegadores podem não reconhecer caracteres acentuados como ã e mostrar um caractere estranho, o charset utf-8 vai dizer dizer que a página está encodificada em unicode que pode mostrar qualquer caractere nessa encodificação https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_utf8.asp

`lang=""` apenas informa a linguagem da página